# Android Tabview Layout with Admob

Tags: android, admob

I have an android XML and I am trying to get the ads to show up at the bottom of a tabview, but they are not showing up. I think I am just missing something very simple, but I have been looking at this for far too long and I hope someone can help me out. Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.Vdrop"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
            <com.admob.android.ads.AdView     
           android:id="@+id/ad" 
           android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:gravity="bottom"
           myapp:backgroundColor="#000000"
           myapp:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
           myapp:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
  />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I figured it out. You basically need to use a relative layout to put an ad on the bottom of the screen so I made one after the linear layout. Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.Vdrop"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.admob.android.ads.AdView     
           android:id="@+id/ad" 
           android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
           myapp:backgroundColor="#000000"
           myapp:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
           myapp:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
  />
  </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use with in LinearLayout. Also you pay attention the layout weight. Here is the XML;

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/app.tabsample"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="1dp"/>
    </LinearLayout> 
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

       <com.admob.android.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" 
    myapp:backgroundColor="#c6360a"
    myapp:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
    myapp:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"/>

   </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works really great!

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TabHost 
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_above="@+id/adView">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>    


   <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="AD_UNITID"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"
                         ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
                         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>


 </RelativeLayout>
```