# Integrate Admob adview into TableLayout / TableRow

Tags: android, admob, android-tablelayout

I'm trying to integrate Admob into my TableLayout. Unfortunately it's never shown on the screen. The layout contains only some textfields on the top, and one mapview, the adview should be placed at the bottom. My XML layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:stretchColumns="1" 
android:id="@+id/main">

<TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="text1"
        android:textSize="25sp" 
        android:layout_span="3"/>
</TableRow>


<TableRow>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="txt2"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_span="3"
    />

</TableRow>

<TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt3"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="txt3"
        android:textSize="25sp" 
        android:paddingLeft="20sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt4"            
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="txt4"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:paddingRight="20sp"/>
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:layout_span="2"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:apiKey="XXX"
    android:clickable="true"
    />
 </TableRow>

<TableRow>

<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="XXX"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                     ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, XXX"
                     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
                     android:layout_span="2"
                     />  
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Can someone tell me what I have to change in order to get the Adview correctly shown?

Comment: Wrap your adview inside some layout? Probably Relative layout and try. Here is reference link from other SO discussion (I know this link is for TabHost not TableLayout, but concept is same)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576117/android-tabview-layout-with-admob

Comment: I already tried it like this, but this also didn't work :(

Comment: are you seeing logs in logcat saying ad feed recieved? If so, it is mostly with your layout settings, play with hieght and width etc.,

Comment: yes,as i'm in test mode. Seems the problem is really the xml. Also if i'm changing the height of the mapview for example to 100px, the Adview is shown. But not if i set height = wrap_content.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way, as I create simple demo for your understand...!?!
I think it helps you

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:shrinkColumns="*"
android:stretchColumns="*" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:background="@drawable/info_headstriplogo"
    android:gravity="top" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibGMapLocationBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_span="2"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@id/ibGMapLocationBack"
        android:src="@drawable/back" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_span="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:apiKey="0zzbEqGyRIg8wikQPkcwDvqhM6x0TwcSHozLlZg"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:background="@drawable/footerstrip"
    android:gravity="bottom" >
</TableRow>
```